# Issues with stopping MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

i have a one layout and 3 buttons and textView , when i cick a button it change the textView , button3 i have a song to play and textView show lyrics, and my problem here is how to make the MediaPlayer stopping when click any other button 
    here is my code i used :

```html
   

public class Langue extends Activity{
 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.langue);
final String St1 ="My topic1"
 Button But1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     But1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Tv.setText(St1);
    // code to make scroll back to up, to start point.
    Tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
                               }
                                                  });
 final String St2="My Topic2"
Button But2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
But2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  TextView Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  Tv.setText(St2);
  // code to make scroll back to up, to start point.
  Tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
                             }
                                            });

final String St3="Lyrics of song iles.mp3"
Button But3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
But3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 
TextView Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Tv.setText(St3);
//code to make scroll back to up, to start point.
Tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
//play song

iles= MediaPlayer.create(Langue.this, R.raw.iles);
iles.start();
}
                                  });
```

Comment: where is the code that you used..

Comment: Post yout code please

Comment: here is my code i added

Comment: @hakim where is  iles variable created ?

Comment: iles is mp3 located in raw file

Comment: a sorry i forget to copy it in code : here is located

Comment: public class Langue extends Activity{
 MediaPlayer iles = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: @hakim ok its no prob ..check the answer i uploaded, u will have to use iles.stop() to stop the song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Langue extends Activity{
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.langue);
final MediaPlayer  iles= MediaPlayer.create(Langue.this, R.raw.iles);//creating iles here
final String St1 ="My topic1"
 Button But1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        But1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                Tv.setText(St1);
                // code to make scroll back to up, to start point.
                Tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
                iles.stop(); // in here the song will stop
                                        }
                                                     });
 final String St2="My Topic2"
Button But2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
But2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Tv.setText(St2);
        // code to make scroll back to up, to start point.
        Tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
        iles.stop(); // in here the song will stop
                                }
                                            });

final String St3="Lyrics of song iles.mp3"
Button But3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
But3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

TextView Tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Tv.setText(St3);
//code to make scroll back to up, to start point.
Tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
//play song
iles.start();
}
                                  });
```

I believe  this will do., in the above code i created a iles as MediaPlayer object and used it to stop the song...

Comment: Thank you Saran i just find it and it worked for me i added this code in each button

Comment: //stop iles.mp3 song if its running
     try{ iles.stop();} catch(Exception e) {}; it is like you answered but i think if you didnt put (try) it will crash when click button1 before running song at all .

Comment: @hakim or you can use something like this in button1 ` if(iles.isPlaying()){iles.stop();} `

Comment: yes is solved thank you very mush@saran .it solved with (try and catch) but i will use  `if(iles.isPlaying()){iles.stop();} ` and see